# postgresql 8.4 and postgis 1.5 error: type modifier is not allowed for type 'geometry'

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I would like to generate a buffer (within a limit of 3km  )  where the user clicked point.
In pgAdmin, select my database and open a query editor and create 2 PostGIS functions (UTM Zone Function and ST_Buffer_Meters Function)

Used following SQL command to create another column in to my table. my table is “schools” with lat and lon fields.
ALTER TABLE schools ADD COLUMN geom_buffer geometry(POLYGON,4326);

but appear error: type modifier is not allowed for type 'geometry'

Why is that..??/ Pls. help me anyone. ..

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Perhaps you wanted to use addGeometryColumn (http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch04.html#Create_Spatial_Table) to ensure that you are really creating a spatial table.

Comment: It may help, in the bigger picture, to upgrade to a newer version of postgis. Is that an option?

Comment: actually, I would like to generate a buffer (within a limit of 3km  )  where the user clicked point and the popup window(table) to appear attribute details of that buffer zone. Please suggest me any ideas of how to carry on this task.... 
I'm trying to create like this  sample (buffer): 
https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/query_buffer.html   Already school network(vector layer) was created  and published using free and open source Web-GIS tools. (postgis+geoserver+openlayer).